# Using Search with RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

I have the following index definitions

```
        public SearchIndex()
    {
        this.Map = users => from user in users
                            select new
                                {
                                    FirstName = user.FirstName, 
                                    LastName = user.LastName, 
                                    MobilePhoneNumber = user.MobilePhoneNumber, 
                                    EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress
                                };
        Index(x => x.FirstName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.LastName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.MobilePhoneNumber, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.EmailAddress, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

    }
```

And I try to use Full Text Search Like so

```
 var s = GetSession().Query<Registrants, StudentSearchIndex>()
                                 .Search(m => m.LastName, lastName, boost: 10, escapeQueryOptions:EscapeQueryOptions.EscapeAll)
                                 .Search(m => m.FirstName, firstName, boost: 5)
                                 .Search(m => m.MobilePhoneNumber, phoneNumber)
                                 .Search(m => m.EmailAddress, emailAddress);
```

However when i use the above expression in code. I get the following error message

Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method 'Raven.Client.Linq.IRavenQueryable`1[Spurro.Data.RavenDB.Models.Registrants] Search[Registrants](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Spurro.Data.RavenDB.Models.Registrants], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Spurro.Data.RavenDB.Models.Registrants,System.Object]], System.String, System.Decimal, Raven.Client.SearchOptions, Raven.Client.EscapeQueryOptions)'

Please What Am I doing Wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error message when a search input (LastName, FirstName... in this case) was null.
Btw, MobilePhoneNumber should be NotAnalyzed.

Answer (score -1):

***Not*** a solution for this as such, but I got here because I had used the following syntax to configure indexing, and ended up with the same error as described in the original question:

```
public SearchIndex()
{
    // Map .....

    Indexes = new Dictionary<Expression<Func<StaffDetail, object>>, FieldIndexing>
    {
        {sd => sd.FirstName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
        {sd => sd.LastName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
        {sd => sd.MobilePhoneNumber, FieldIndexing.Analyzed},
        {sd => sd.EmailAddress, FieldIndexing.Analyzed}
    };
}
```

The correct approach is as per the original question.